# How to add a new line after return keyword for JavaScript in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

From this code format:

```
return ( <div>
        <h1>The Home Page</h1>
        <form onSubmit={ submitFormHandler }>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='email'>Your Email Address</label>
                <input type='email' id='email' ref={ emailInputRef }></input>
            </div>
            <button> Send feedback</button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

...to this, I want!

```
return ( 
    <div>
        <h1>The Home Page</h1>
        <form onSubmit={ submitFormHandler }>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='email'>Your Email Address</label>
                <input type='email' id='email' ref={ emailInputRef }></input>
            </div>
            <button> Send feedback</button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

Please tell me the setting to achieve the expected format.

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect for JavaScript, but there's no functional difference between the two forms. Go solve a real problem.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I know that but I like that format.. so asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a `Prettier` package way of formatting.